# SQL Query to Count total rows grouping different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that has RMA return data.  I want to write a query to return the total number of times a unit has been returned (each return has a unique RMA Number). I also need to return the number of times a unit has returned multiple times, and the number of times it returned for the same symptom. A record is created each time the unit goes to a station (RMA, symptom, and date returned is propagated for each station record).

The data looks like this:

```
ID      SN     RMA     SYMPTOM          Station        Date_Returned
21567   A001   84704   POWER FAULT      DockRecv       01/01/2015
21568   A001   84704   POWER FAULT      Repair         01/01/2015
21569   A001   84704   POWER FAULT      Ship           01/01/2015

10235   A002   83494   NO DISPLAY       DockRecv       02/20/2015 
10236   A002   83494   NO DISPLAY       Repair         02/20/2015
10237   A002   83494   NO DISPLAY       Ship           02/20/2015

36548   A002   84283   ABNORMAL NOISE   DockRecv       10/05/2015
36549   A002   84283   ABNORMAL NOISE   Repair         10/05/2015
36550   A002   84283   ABNORMAL NOISE   Ship           10/05/2015

38790   A003   83432   HDD FAULT        DockRecv       09/15/2015
38791   A003   83432   HDD FAULT        Repair         09/15/2015
38792   A003   83432   HDD FAULT        Ship           09/15/2015

69613   A003   84276   HDD FAULT        DockRecv       01/30/2016
69614   A003   84276   HDD FAULT        Repair         01/30/2016
69615   A003   84276   HDD FAULT        Ship           01/30/2016

56732   A004   82011   NFF              DockRecv       12/01/2015
56733   A004   82011   NFF              Repair         12/01/2015
56734   A004   82011   NFF              Ship           12/01/2015
```

My Output needs to look like this:

```
Total_Returns   Repeat_Return   Same_Symptom_Return
6               2               1
```

A001(RMA 84704) is a single return.

A002 is a multiple return-(RMA 83494) is the first return (after repaired, the unit is shipped out) after some time in the field, the unit is returned again A002(RMA 84283).... When a unit is returned, it goes through 3 stations (we create a record for each station (propagating the RMA, symptom, and date returned for each station record).

I can get Total_Returns with the code:

```
Select count(*) as totalcount
From
(
     SELECT     
        [SN]
       ,[RMA]
     FROM [dbo].[test]
     Group by [SN],[RMA]
)as a
```

Comment: what is your rdbms and version? And in your sample are 4 distinct RMA, so why total_returns is 6?

Comment: yes, it's 6 for total returns.... running sql server 6.1.7601

Comment: why is 6? what count total_returns?

Comment: Your sample data and expected results don't make sense.  Your `distinct` count of `rma` is 5, then the repeated count should be 1 for both.  If you replace `83494` with `84704`, then you could get your sample expected results, but...

Comment: Also your `Repeat_Return` and `Same_symptom` doesnt match with your expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: each SN / RMA combination is a return.

Comment: what is a repeat_return and what is same_symptom ?

Comment: A001(RMA 84704) is a return, A002(RMA 83494) is the first return (after repaired, unit is shipped out) after some time in the field, the unit is returned again A002(RMA 84283).... When a unit is returned, it goes through 3 test stations (we record a record for each test station - there are other fields not listed for each record - like date/time at each station, pass/fail inf.ect.).

Comment: A003 is a same symptom return.  The first time it was returned it was diagnosed as HDD FAULT.  When A003 was returned again, it was diagnosed the same as the previous return.

Comment: What is the data that is identifiable as unique so we can count it to 6? Right now there is no data/column on your sample that we can use to group, therefore impossible to have your desired result data something important is missing like machineId or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 quite different methods needed to arrive at the counts, so I have used 3 separate sub-queries. see this working at sqlfiddle (but not on MS SQL Server) here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9df16/1

Result:

```
| Total_Count | Repeat_Return | Same_Symptom_Return |
|-------------|---------------|---------------------|
|           6 |             2 |                   1 |
```

Query:

```
select
    (select count(distinct SN + RMA + SYMPTOM) from table1) as Total_Count
,   (select count(*) from(
         SELECT  SN
         FROM table1
         Group by SN
         having count(distinct Date_Returned) > 1)
     ) as Repeat_Return
,   (select count(*) from(
         SELECT  SYMPTOM  
         FROM table1
         Group by SYMPTOM  
         having count(*)/3 > 1)
     ) as Same_Symptom_Return
```

note: you should include "sql server" as a tag on your question (well I presum it is that because of the **[dbo].[test]**

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work... I'm sure there is a more streamline way to write it...

```
SELECT
-- Get Total_Returned Count
(Select distinct
count(*) as 'Total_Returned'
From
(   SELECT     
        [SN]
       ,[RMA]
    FROM [dbo].[test]
    Group by [SN],[RMA]
)a) AS 'Total_Returned'
-- Get Repeat_Return Count
,(Select distinct
[Repeat_Return] - COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Repeat_Return]     
From
(   SELECT
         COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Repeat_Return]     
        ,[SN]
        ,[RMA]
    FROM [dbo].[test]
    Group by [SN],[RMA]
)a Group by [SN],[Repeat_Return]) AS 'Repeat_Return'
-- Get Same_Symptom_Return Count
,(Select distinct 
[Same_Symptom_Return] - COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Same_Symptom_Return]     
From
(   SELECT
         COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Same_Symptom_Return]     
        ,[SN]
        ,[RMA]
        ,SYMPTOM
    FROM [dbo].[test]
    Group by SN, SYMPTOM, RMA
)a Group by [SN], SYMPTOM, [Same_Symptom_Return]) AS 'Same_Symptom_Return'
```

Result:

```
|Total_Returned | Repeat_Return | Same_Symptom_Return |
|---------------|---------------|---------------------|
|             6 |             2 |                   1 |
```